# Can I use a SQL database to share datasets?

Tags: python, sql-server, machine-learning, cloud

Is it possible to set-up a SQL database server on my personal desktop and use it as a point of access for a group project (the project isn't the SQL but about Machine Learning)? I have in my hands a large volume of data (100GB) and I was thinking in order to manipulate the data amongst our team to set up a SQL server online, and access it through R Studio or Python (I can download SQL Enterprise from my university for free as a student). 
Is this possible, and if yes what would I need, for example do I need to buy a web host service?
The reason for this is apart from the accessibility to the data the fact that I could create more tables that contain the manipulated data and each person access them easily. At least that's what I have in my mind.

Comment: Yes. Its common to host a sql database on a separate server with many client accessors.

Comment: You can certainly do it but you'll have to keep in mind that you're spinning up a server so your desktop will have to be on during the duration of the project. You'll have to know what port your server is listening from. And if you're behind a firewall, you'll have to port forward that port to your desktop's local IP. And no, you don't need to buy a web host service. Also, your teammates will need the ODBC drivers to connect to the DB, as well as the ODBC connection string.

Comment: That actually is really helpful. I can use your steps on google to find appropriate guides how to "bring" a server online and offer access to my teammates. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can share a local SQL database, here there is a tutorial (among many other) of how to do that (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UkHYNwUtCo).
The problem is that 100 GB of information in a local machine maybe is not a good idea if you want the data to be accesible for other people. Maybe, you explore the idea of using NoSQL databases (key-value or document-oriented) to access the data in a rapid manner.

Comment: The data though is purely numerical (transformed images to probability values), and from the very little knowledge I have on DB's NoSQL is optimised for social networks, no?

Comment: No, NoSql databases are multipurpose. It's true that because of the nature of social networks that have to process big amounts of data they use them more.
As your data is a representation of images and for each image there is some information attached, a document-oriented NoSQL database like CouchDB may work fine. Just a suggestion ;-)

Comment: Ah, ok. I will check this out. What NoSQL databases are in the market and if my uni offers for free any of them

Comment: I wouldn't go down the noSQL route. It'll be harder to do complex data manipulations. Better to stick with relational. But what Steven said in the below answer is valid. Your home network will probably be a bottleneck if you have concurrent users hitting your DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can quite easily use nearly any database for this dataset. But with a reasonably large dataset like this you should consider running the database somewhere centralised rather than using your local system for that.

If possible try to use SQL for the data manipulation where possible since that will be run by the DBMS in the most efficient way it can do. Otherwise you are pulling out data and putting it back in.

See https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseProgramming for more background on this.